# How can i get json data from javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have request

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://translate.google.ru/translate_a/t',
        data: { client: "x", text: sourceText, sl: langFrom, tl: langTo },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        }
```

In response to this process i have file t.js .
The contents of this file is

```
{
    "sentences":[{
        "trans":"был в школе",
        "orig":"був в школі",
        "translit":"byl v shkole",
        "src_translit":"buv v shkoli"
        }],
    "src":"uk",
    "server_time":40
    }
```

But in dragonfly i have javascript error

```
Syntax error at line 1 while loading:
{"sentences":[{"trans":"вход вых
------------^
expected ';', got ':'
```

I need get trans obj.

Comment: Why are you using JSONp and not just JSON? JSONp is typically used for cross domain 'requests'.

Comment: It's the same case. I need cross domain 'requests'.

Comment: It IS a cross domain request. The url starts with `http://translate.google.ru/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$.getJSON()` function instead of `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Sasha : then use JSON.parse() function to convert a string into a JSON format